# How to split the the strings of column in a data frame and save them in different columns?

Tags: r

I have a data like this, From the string of time Period Column, I want separate them and save them in Week, Month and Year columns which are highlighted in yellow. [Please find the data below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUiNL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract`:

```
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  extract(Date,
          into = c("Day", "Month", "Year"),
          regex = ".*(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)")
  Day Month Year
1   1     1 2018
2   5     2 2021
```

If you want to keep the original dates, use `remove = FALSE`:

```
df %>%
  extract(Date,
          into = c("Day", "Month", "Year"),
          regex = ".*(\\d+)-(\\d+)-(\\d+)",
          remove = FALSE)
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1-1-2018", "15-2-2021")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use `lubridate` library:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(Date = lubridate::dmy(Date)) %>% 
  mutate(Day = lubridate::day(Date),
         Month = lubridate::month(Date),
         Year = lubridate::year(Date))


# Date Day Month Year
# 1 2018-01-01   1     1 2018
# 2 2021-02-15  15     2 2021
```

data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("1-1-2018", "15-2-2021")
)
```